# How to write Rspec HTTP method to hit a nested show view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a rails route like this:

```
get 'posts/:category/:permalink',  to: 'blog/posts#show',  as: :post
```

Rake routes tells me this information about the above route:

```
post GET    /posts/:category/:permalink(.:format)     blog/posts#show
```

I am just trying to write the correct RSpec http method to test that it renders a show template.

```
require 'spec_helper'

module Blog
  RSpec.describe PostsController, type: :controller do
    describe '#show' do
      it 'renders show template' do
        get :show, {category: 'tech', permalink: 'great-post'}
        expect(response).to render_template('show')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However this rspec test is getting the following error:

```
F

Failures:

  1) Blog::PostsController#show renders show template
     Failure/Error: get :show, {category: 'tech', permalink: 'great-post'}

     ArgumentError:
       unknown keywords: category, permalink
     # ./spec/controllers/blog/posts/show_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Blog>'
```

Does anyone know how to correctly draw this method in rspec to reach the Blog::PostsController#show ?

`get :show, {category: 'tech', permalink: 'great-post'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `category` and `permalink` as `params`:

```
module Blog
  RSpec.describe PostsController, type: :controller do
    describe '#show' do
      it 'renders show template' do
        get :show, params: { category: 'tech', permalink: 'great-post' }
        expect(response).to render_template('show')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: For more context, this changed a couple of Rails releases ago; in older versions, the spelling in the question would've worked.